# Using Savon 2.12.0, multiple responses arrive in an array, but a single reponse is a hash

Tags: savon

I'm successfully calling an operation using Savon to get data from a SOAP endpoint. Each returned object is a hash of ~15 elements.

When the API needs to return multiple objects, it returns them in an array, eg:
data = [{ key1a => val1a, key1b => val1b, key1c => val1c }, { key2a => val2a, key2b => val2b, key2c => val2c }, { key3a => val3a, key3b => val3b, key3c => val3c }]

This lets me iterate through responses with a data.each and then break apart the hash within the block.

If i get a single response, it returns just the Hash not enclosed in an Array. This means that when i run a .each against it, it's looking at Hash elements (key1a, etc)

data = { key => val, key2 => val2, key3 => val3 }

To get around this, i've had to run a .class against the returned object and treat it differently if it's an Array or a Hash.

I had a look at the raw returned data from the API and the markup structure looks the same, so i suspect this is Savon behavior more than API behavior.

Any way of changing this? Not sure if it's a "bug" as such, but certainly makes my code look messier than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use the splat operator

```
data = *{ key: 'val', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3' }
```

it coerces the hash into an array of arrays. I used it a lot in my Savon sources.

Comment: Hoping to get an array of hashes if that's possible - i guess i could just wrap a returned hash into [] with a conditional right?